# "The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory" when loading the view Direclty (not when Naivgating from other page)

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angularjs-routing

I'm extending an existing Angular-MVC.NET application.
There are two features: transformations (exisitng) and embossing (the one I'm creating). Both of them use provider classes that call an underlying logic.

[image]

I copied all the logic for the transformation (Angular and MVC model and views), renamed evrthing accordingly, and created the new route for this feature in `app.router.js`

```
            $routeProvider.when('/embossing', {
                templateUrl: 'app/views/embossing.html',
                params: { test: "hola" },
                resolve: {
                    deps: [
                        "$ocLazyLoad", function (a) {
                            debugger;
                            return a.load([jqload.c3, jqload.sparkline])
                                .then(function () {
                                    return a.load({
                                        name: "app.directives",
                                        files: ["app/scripts/lazyload/directives/sparkline.directive.js"]
                                    });
                                })
                                .then(function () {
                                    return a.load("angular-c3");
                                })
                                .then(function () {
                                    return a.load("easypiechart");
                                });
                        }
                    ]
                }
            });
```

Now I'm able to navigate without issues from the angular transformation controller to the embossing view  by using
`$location.path('/embossing');`

The thing that happens is that when I load directly the view by entering `http://localhost:1623/embossing/` or if I hit enter on the browrser's URL bar after navegating from transformation (as I mentioned before) I get this error

[image]

How come I'm able to navigate to the view but when I load it directly I get that error?
Is there something that I'm missing? What could be wrong?

Thanks

Comment: do you have html5Mode enabled in angular config? If not need to use hash in url. If so need to configure server for the virtual directories being used

Comment: @charlietfl. Thank you very much! You are on the right spot! Using the # worked, but I don't know how I can enable html5Mode mode, do you have any link that could have a deeper axplanation about this?

Comment: actually, html5 is enabled `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`
The problem is only with one view (embosser). The rest of the views are loading properly when I enter their URL directly

Comment: same server configuration that allows one to load should let other. Don't understand why you have directories on server that match routes in angular. Angular is single page app using virtual server directory paths and those virtual paths on server should always load the root of the angular app

Comment: Might find this relevant: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/06/25/aspnetmvc-block-view-access.aspx/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MVC and AngularJS Routing - 403.14 - Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29021375/mvc-and-angularjs-routing-403-14-forbidden)

It got solved by renaming the "Embossing" folder (the one that contains EmbossingProvider.cs)

It seems that there cannot be a folder name as a route. eg:

$routeProvider.when('/embossing', was conflicting with "Embossing" folder